# Loading payment gateway page in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, url, payment-gateway

I have a payment gateway which I want to integrate with codeigniter. I am getting values from view using ajax. I need to redirect to the payment gateway page with some values so that the user can do the further process in the payment gateway page.

My view which passes the values

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loader").hide();
    $("#connectionForm").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/home/save_new_connection');?>",
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            // async:false,
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: true,
            processData:false,

            success: function(data)
            {   

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my controller which process the values

```
public function save_new_connection()
{
    $data['name']=$name=$this->input->post('name');
    $data['amount']=$amount=$this->input->post('amount');
    $url='https://abcd.com/servlet';
    include APPPATH . 'class/NetworkonlieBitmapPaymentIntegration.php';
    $networkOnlineArray['Field_Existence_Indicator_Transaction']['amount']=$amount;
    $networkOnlineArray['Field_Existence_Indicator_Billing']['billToFirstName']=$name;
    $networkOnlineObject=new NetworkonlieBitmapPaymentIntegration($networkOnlineArray);
    $data['requestParameter']=$requestParameter;
    redirect("https://abcd.com/servlet".$requestParameter);
```

I need to send the $requestParameter to the $url so that the payment gateway page will be shown to the user, I used curl as an option but it's not redirecting to the payment gateway page. I tried to pass the values back to ajax, but the "echo" which place after `include APPPATH. 'class/NetworkonlieBitmapPaymentIntegration.php';` is not working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save values entered by the user, then this method will work, but if you do not need to save anything, the best option is to have the form post directly to the payment gateway.

Here's how you can accomplish this using ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loader").hide();
    $("#connectionForm").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/home/save_new_connection');?>",
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            // async:false,
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: true,
            processData:false,

            success: function(data)
            {   
                window.location.href=data;
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>


public function save_new_connection()
{
    $data['name']=$name=$this->input->post('name');
    $data['amount']=$amount=$this->input->post('amount');
    $url='https://abcd.com/servlet';
    include APPPATH . 'class/NetworkonlieBitmapPaymentIntegration.php';
    $networkOnlineArray['Field_Existence_Indicator_Transaction']['amount']=$amount;
    $networkOnlineArray['Field_Existence_Indicator_Billing']['billToFirstName']=$name;
    $networkOnlineObject=new NetworkonlieBitmapPaymentIntegration($networkOnlineArray);
    $data['requestParameter']=$requestParameter;

    echo "https://abcd.com/servlet".$requestParameter;

}
```